# Set div on condition is true or false javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys i am trying to do a password validation script with java css and html but its not working and do not know why i tried varies ways to do so but none of them works for me :

javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).attr("name")=="repassword".keyup(validate);
});


function validate() {
  var password1 = $(this).attr("name")=="password".val();
  var password2 = $(this).attr("name")=="repassword".val();



    if(password1 == password2) {
       $(this).attr("name")=="password".g.setAttribute("id", "valid");
       $(this).attr("name")=="repassword".g.setAttribute("id", "valid");
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr("name")=="repassword".g.setAttribute("id", "invalid");
    }

}
```

css :

```
#valid {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,0,1);
   background: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,255,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0,255,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px rgba(0,255,0,1);

}

#invalid {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
   background: #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px rgba(255,0,0,1);

}
```

html:

```
            password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            Re-Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="repassword"><br>
```

so i am trying just to validate if password mach and if they mach give password and repassword input field id=valid if not repassword invalid i got no result at all so somewhere probably made a mistake , cuz i am just starting coding with javascript

Comment: You repeatedly use this construct: `$(this).attr("name")=="something".val()` - what are you trying to do here? Did you mean `$(this).find("[name=something]").val()`?

Comment: $(this).attr("name")=="repassword".keyup(validate); just tell check input where name is == to repassword

Comment: You should use attribute selector then. Check: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Open your console (hit F12 on Windows or Opt + Cmd + I on Mac). You're going to see some errors using that weird construct. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to give your html tags an id attribute, then I strongly recommend doing it. If done correctly you will have a unique way to access each element. For most cases the id element should be static, and should not be the one you are changing. However, "just" to answer your question I will give you a quick solution.

```
$("input[name*='password']").attr('id', 'valid');
```

I recommend doing something like this in the future though...

```
<input id="password" valid="false"/>
<input id="repassword" valid="true"/>
$("#password").attr('valid', 'false');
```

Comment: my function is works for checking the password mach but its not working when it have to set id for inputs

Comment: Updated to match your comment... You may want to update your question, if its specifically about changing the attribute.